# How to use getline function more clearly

Tags: c++, function, getline

Recently , I declare some char array and made a function named InputValue that gets char* str;
but I try to change array to string and get same information by using getline function.
I know that by using getline, i can do it.
but I want to put getline in my InputValue function and using it.
In this case, how can i change my InputValue function.
below, there is my InputValue function.

```
inline void InputValue(char* str) {     
cin >> str;
};
```

Comment: This is a fragile function. `operator>>` doesn't have a clue how large the array is that `str` points at. Why not use `std::string`?

Comment: `std::cin.getline(str, count)`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- re: "Why not use `std::string`?" -- the question asks how to do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker It does - it's not just shown in the code what's been tried.

Comment: @minsg: Did you try `void InputValue(std::string& str) { std::cin >> str; }`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- sorry to have been too diplomatic. When someone asks "how do I do X", responding with "why don't you do X?" is not at all helpful.

Comment: @PeteBecker :-) You got your point through. I should have phrased my question, "what happened when you tried replacing it with a `std::string&`?" or "how did you try replacing it with a `std::string`? Please show _that_ code in addition to the code you're trying to replace."